# `gcloud builds submit` silently failing during github actions step

Tags: google-cloud-platform, github-actions, google-cloud-run

During a PR-triggered deploy to Google Cloud Run, I am encountering issues, as my container build and push are failing. There is no error messaging or logging available. From the provided [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AH1dh.png), the command is assumed to have run without any error, and yet the build is not displayed in Cloud Build's build history. Despite utilizing `--verbosity=debug`, github actions is not providing any logging. I have searched the GCP console but have been unable to find any logs related to the `gcloud builds submit` command. I am unsure of the best course of action and would appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score -1):

just remove the `\` after your `echo`. This is used to wrap long lines in most shells. So instead of executing `gcloud builds submit` the command is printed on the screen.